# mdbreact datatable pagination issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap-table, mdbreact

Im using [mdbreact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdbreact) package to display the data in a datatable. In the datatable I have a column with checkbox to change the value. When I check or Uncheck and move to the second page, the values of the checkbox in the second page is also changing. How do I sort this issue?